# Issue while extracting hidden value of input tag using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

CSSExtractor is not working for below response. I have used "input[name=__Token]" CSS expression. can you please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" abc="SDFSDFDSFDss=">
    window['variables'] = {
        hiddenToken: '<input name="__Token" type="hidden" value="dsfdflkjzcjkjljj" />',
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it doesn't because it's inside [`<script>` block](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) hence it's not available in [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) directly, you need to switch to the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and the regular expression like:

```
input name="__Token".*value="(.+?)"
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)